# How to get full path from FileItem

Tags: java, file, file-upload, upload, zip

How to get full path from FileItem and put into FileInputStream, seems like i can only getName. Below is my code, im trying to upload file and auto zip into server. Thank you

```
DiskFileItemFactory fup = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fup);

List items = upload.parseRequest(req);
Iterator iter = items.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();                             
                if (!item.isFormField()) {

                File f = new File(Properties.get("dir") + File.separator + "test.zip");
                ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
                ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(flNm);
                out.putNextEntry(e);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream((File) item);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.closeEntry();

                out.close();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a `File` object that refers to a newly created tempfile which is empty. And writing it into a file. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Hi, Sorry my bad. I want to ask how to put FileItem into FileInputStream in java? I got my code "FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();" and want to put item to FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream();